TCP Client NetworkStream ReadAsync Hanging
I am trying to implement TCP communication in a Windows Form App. The user clicks a button and a command is sent successfully, but I am having trouble getting the result of the command back using readAsync. The result should display in a label element in the Windows form.
I would like to throw a timeout excpetion if I haven't received a response in 5 seconds. My code is as follows:
private async void command_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label.Text += "button pressed ";
    Task<string> resultstring = send_DMCC_command_async("command");
    label.Text += resultstring.Result;  
}
...
private async Task<string> send_DMCC_command_async(string command)
{
    try
    {
        // using a timeout of 1 second
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
        {
            using (var client = new TcpClient(device_ip, port)) // device ip and port are declared elsewhere
            using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                // convert message to byte array
                Byte[] command_bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command + "\r\n");
                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer.
                stream.Write(command_bytes, 0, command_bytes.Length);

                // Buffer to store the response response_bytes_count and ASCII representation.
                Byte[] response_bytes = new Byte[256];

                // wait for response, and throw an exception if it takes more than 5 seconds
                Int32 response_bytes_count = -1;
                Task<Int32> readTask = stream.ReadAsync(response_bytes, 0, response_bytes.Length, cts.Token);
                response_bytes_count = await readTask;
                String result_string = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response_bytes, 0, response_bytes_count);
                return await Task.FromResult(result_string);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(ex.ToString());
    }
}

The trickiest thing is that when I put a breakpoint in the send_DMCC_command_async function and step through the code, I get the response from the connection. But when I run the code without the breakpoint, it hangs. The response comes instantly when I send the command via a different interface, so I don't think the timeout is the issue, but I've tried increasing the timeout and that hasn't made a difference.
I think I'm misunderstanding how readAsync works- I'd like to know why my code is hanging, and what I can do to change it. Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

what is the point of return await Task.FromResult() ... in async Task<T> method you can just do return x ...  also resultstring.Result in command_button_Click look wrong why didn't you use await resultstring  or var resultstring = await send_DMCC_command_async("command")

See Don't Block on Async Code by Stephen Cleary.

Why label.Text += resultstring.Result; and not label.Text += await resultstring;?

Thank you @TheodorZoulias, that was a very helpful resource! I needed to await my send_dmcc_command function, it's no longer freezing. Once I have a bit of time I'll add my updated code and mark it as closed.
